# How to count number of occurrences by using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to use pyspark to count the number of occurrences.

Suppose I have data like this:

```
data = sc.parallelize([(1,[u'a',u'b',u'd']),
                       (2,[u'a',u'c',u'd']),
                       (3,[u'a']) ])

count = sc.parallelize([(u'a',0),(u'b',0),(u'c',0),(u'd',0)])
```

Is possible to count the number of occurrences in `data` and update in `count`?

The result should be like `[(u'a',3),(u'b',1),(u'c',1),(u'd',2)]`.

Answer (score 6):

I would use `Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
>>> data.values().map(Counter).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y)
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 2})
```

Answer (score 3):

RDDs are immutable and thus cannot be updated. Instead, you compute the *count*  based on your *data*  as:

```
count = (rdd
         .flatMap(lambda (k, data): data)
         .map(lambda w: (w,1))
         .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b))
```

Then, if the result can fit in master main memory feel free to .collect() from *count*.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't *update* `count` since RDDs are immutable. Just run the calculation you want and then save directly to any variable you want:

```
In [17]: data.flatMap(lambda x: x[1]).map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y).collect()
Out[17]: [('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 2), ('a', 3)]
```